# XML won't validate with schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I'm using http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html to validate my XML file. Getting the following message

"Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'MatchedShareReport'.. Line '2', Column '21'."

Here is the schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.k12345.com/Data/k12345.xsd"   targetNamespace="http://www.k12345.com/Data/k12345.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">

 <xsd:element name="MatchedShareReport">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="FileHeader" type="tns:FileHeader" />
            <xsd:element name="UsageDescription" type="tns:UsageDescription" />
            <xsd:element name="UsageList" type="tns:UsageList" />           
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="FileHeader"> 
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FileId" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileParentId" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileSender" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileReceiver" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileDSPName" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileDescription" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileGroupId" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileGroupDescription" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="FileTimeStamp" type="xsd:dateTime" />        
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>  

<xsd:complexType name="UsageDescription">   
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FilePeriod"> 
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="StartDate" type="xsd:date" />        
                    <xsd:element name="EndDate" type="xsd:date" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>  

<xsd:complexType name="UsageList">  
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Usage" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="RecordingDetails" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingTitle" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingVersionTitle" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingDisplayArtist" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingISRC" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />      
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingDSPId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />     
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="WorkDetails" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="WorkPrimaryTitle" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkISWC" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkK12345Id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />                                     
                                <xsd:element name="WorkSTIMStatus" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkDisputeStatus" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkLastAmendedDate" type="xsd:date" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkI123Ids">
                                    <xsd:complexType>  
                                                   <xsd:sequence>
                                                        <xsd:element name="WorkI123Id" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                                   </xsd:sequence>
                                              </xsd:complexType>                                             
                                         </xsd:element>
                                         <xsd:element name="WorkWriterList">      
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element name="WorkWriter" maxOccurs="unbounded">   
                                                <xsd:complexType>
                                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                                        <xsd:element name="WriterName" type="xsd:string" />
                                                        <xsd:element name="WriterIPINumber" type="xsd:string" />
                                                                       <xsd:element name="WriterK12345MechanicalPerc" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />      
                                                                       <xsd:element name="WriterK12345PerformingPerc" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />                   
                                                                       <xsd:element name="WriterSocietyCodePerformance" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />                                                                         
                                                                       <xsd:element name="WriterSocietyCodeMechanical" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />                                                                           
                                                                  </xsd:sequence>
                                                </xsd:complexType>
                                            </xsd:element>                                              
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>  
                    <xsd:element name="UsageDetails" minOccurs="1">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="UsageTerritory" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="UsageCommercialModelType" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="UsageType" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="UsageDistributionChannelType" type="xsd:string" />     
                                <xsd:element name="UsageCurrency" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />    
                                <xsd:element name="UsageValue" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true" />
                                <xsd:element name="UsageQuantity" type="xsd:integer" />
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>          
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>  

<xsd:complexType name="MWRUsageList">   
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Usage" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="RecordingDetails" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingTitle" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingVersionTitle" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingDisplayArtist" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingISRC" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />      
                                <xsd:element name="RecordingDSPId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />     
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="WorkDetails" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="WorkPrimaryTitle" type="xsd:string" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkISWC" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkK12345Id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />                                     
                                <xsd:element name="WorkSTIMStatus" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkDisputeStatus" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkLastAmendedDate" type="xsd:date" />
                                <xsd:element name="WorkI123Ids">
                                             <xsd:complexType> 
                                              <xsd:sequence>
                                                   <xsd:element name="WorkI123Id" type="xsd:string" />
                                              </xsd:sequence>
                                              </xsd:complexType>
                                         </xsd:element>                                 
                                         <xsd:element name="WorkWriterList">      
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element name="WorkWriter" maxOccurs="unbounded">   
                                                <xsd:complexType>
                                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                                        <xsd:element name="WriterName" type="xsd:string" />
                                                        <xsd:element name="WriterIPINumber" type="xsd:string" />                                            
                                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                                </xsd:complexType>
                                            </xsd:element>                                              
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>  
                        <xsd:element name="UsageDetails" minOccurs="1">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="UsageTerritory" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:element name="UsageCommercialModelType" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:element name="UsageType" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:element name="UsageDistributionChannelType" type="xsd:string" />     
                                    <xsd:element name="UsageCurrency" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />    
                                    <xsd:element name="UsageValue" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true" />
                                    <xsd:element name="UsageQuantity" type="xsd:integer" />                                         
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>          
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

The test XML file I am using is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <MatchedShareReport>
      <FileHeader>
           <FileId>FileID123</FileId>
           <FileParentId></FileParentId>
           <FileSender>FileSender</FileSender>
           <FileReceiver>FileReceiver</FileReceiver>
           <FileDSPName>FileDSPName</FileDSPName>
           <FileDescription>FileDescriptionFileDescription</FileDescription>
           <FileGroupId></FileGroupId>
           <FileGroupDescription></FileGroupDescription>
           <FileTimeStamp>2013-06-28T10:51:37</FileTimeStamp>
      </FileHeader>
      <UsageDescription>
           <FilePeriod>
                <StartDate>2013-04-01</StartDate>
                <EndDate>2013-04-30</EndDate>
           </FilePeriod>
      </UsageDescription>
      <UsageList>
           <Usage>
                <WorkDetails>
                     <WorkPrimaryTitle>WorkPrimaryTitle123</WorkPrimaryTitle>
                     <WorkISWC>T9053880867</WorkISWC>
                     <WorkK12345Id></WorkK12345Id>
                     <WorkSTIMStatus>1</WorkSTIMStatus>
                     <WorkDisputeStatus>N</WorkDisputeStatus>
                     <WorkLastAmendedDate>2013-06-28</WorkLastAmendedDate>
                     <WorkI123Ids>
                          <WorkI123Id>6192912</WorkI123Id>
                          <WorkI123Id>6192913</WorkI123Id>
                          <WorkI123Id>6192914</WorkI123Id>
                          <WorkI123Id>6192915</WorkI123Id>
                          <WorkI123Id>6192916</WorkI123Id>
                          <WorkI123Id>6192917</WorkI123Id>
                     </WorkI123Ids>
                     <WorkWriterList>
                          <WorkWriter>
                               <WriterName>LNAME, FNAME</WriterName>
                               <WriterIPINumber>261210876</WriterIPINumber>
                               <WriterK12345MechanicalPerc>052</WriterK12345MechanicalPerc>
                               <WriterK12345PerformingPerc>099</WriterK12345PerformingPerc>
                               <WriterSocietyCodePerformance>0220</WriterSocietyCodePerformance>
                               <WriterSocietyCodeMechanical>416545</WriterSocietyCodeMechanical>
                          </WorkWriter>
                          <WorkWriter>
                               <WriterName>LNAME, FNAME</WriterName>
                               <WriterIPINumber>261221610484</WriterIPINumber>
                               <WriterK12345MechanicalPerc>052</WriterK12345MechanicalPerc>
                               <WriterK12345PerformingPerc>099</WriterK12345PerformingPerc>
                               <WriterSocietyCodePerformance>665</WriterSocietyCodePerformance>
                               <WriterSocietyCodeMechanical>11321</WriterSocietyCodeMechanical>
                          </WorkWriter>
                     </WorkWriterList>
                </WorkDetails>
                <UsageDetails>
                     <UsageTerritory>GB</UsageTerritory>
                     <UsageCommercialModelType>Premium</UsageCommercialModelType>
                     <UsageType>OnDemandStream</UsageType>
                     <UsageDistributionChannelType>Internet</UsageDistributionChannelType>
                     <UsageCurrency>GBP</UsageCurrency>
                     <UsageValue>0.00</UsageValue>
                     <UsageQuantity>128</UsageQuantity>
                </UsageDetails>
           </Usage>

      </UsageList>
 </MatchedShareReport>
```

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it as I've been stuck for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema has a target namespace `http://www.k12345.com/Data/k12345.xsd`. You must use that in your instance document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <MatchedShareReport xmlns="http://www.k12345.com/Data/k12345.xsd">
   <FileHeader>
 ...
```